# Constructing a function $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(a, b)$ is an integer if and only if $a, b$ are integers.

Tags: functions, integers

> What are some examples of functions $f(a,b)$ that is an integer if and only if when $a$ and $b$ are both integers? We require that $f$ be continuous, though not necessarily differentiable, and that we only use elementary functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" formula? I don't think two asymptotes can determine a curve. One can imagine a family of such curves.

Comment: @Travis: Your edit has seriously changed the question. Now the simple example ${1\over3}\bigl(\sin^2(\pi x)+\sin^2(\pi y)\bigr)$ does the job.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I know, that was deliberate: If you check the edit history of the question, you'll see that the question is now the same as the question that was originally posed (except that OP has effectively) replaced "only if" with "if and only if". I gave an answer giving exactly the example you describe (see below), after which OP edited the question specifically disallowing the use of trigonometric functions (which of course are more or less universally considered "elementary"), invalidating my answer. OP then replied to my post asking me to see the change to the question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I rolled back the relevant change per the reply (from a sitting moderator) in this meta thread: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/155629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** A function $$f(x, y) = g(x, y)^2 + h(x, y)^2$$ is zero precisely where $g$ and $h$ are. So, pick a function $j : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that vanishes only at integer values $t$ and is suitably bounded and set $g(x, y) = j(x)$ and  $h(x, y) =  j(y)$.

> For example, $$\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \qquad t \mapsto \sin \pi t$$ vanishes only at integers $t$, so $$\boxed{f(x, y) := \frac{1}{3} (\sin^2 \pi x + \sin^2 \pi y)}$$ vanishes exactly when both $x$ and $y$ are integers. On the other hand, $$0 \leq |f(x, y)| \leq \frac{1}{3}(1 + 1) < 1 ,$$ so $0$ is the only integer value $f$ assumes.

**Remark** Any two integers in the image $\operatorname{im} f$ of such a function $f$ must be consecutive, and in particular $\operatorname{im} f$ contains no more than two integers. Suppose not: Let $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ be integer points where $f$ takes on nonconsecutive integer values $c_1, c_2$, say, $c_1 < a < c_2$ for some integer $a$, and pick a path $\gamma : [t_1, t_2] \to \Bbb R^2$ connecting those points not passing through any other integer points. Then, $f \circ \gamma$ is a continuous function $[t_1, t_2] \to \Bbb R$ satisfying $(f \circ \gamma)(t_i) = f(x_i, y_i) = c_i$, $i = 1, 2$, and the Intermediate Value Theorem says that there is some $t \in I$ such that $f(f \circ \gamma)(t) = a$, so $f$ takes on the integer value $a$ at the noninteger point $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: Please look at my edited question.

Comment: Per this meta thread it is inappropriate (and it is arguably disrespectful) to change questions in ways that invalidate answers consistent with the spirit of the question. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/155629 I've rolled back the question (but preserved the change from "only if" to "if and only if"). If you still want an answer to the modified question, ask it as a separate, new question (and link this one). For what it's worth, trigonometric functions are more or less universally considered elementary.

Comment: Well, I meant to put the trig functions restriction (since I already knew functions like the one you gave), but I must have forgot about it. It was only when you put the function you gave that I remembered.

Comment: That's fine---we all forget things---but the standard advice to post the intended question as a new question (instead of invalidating answers here) applies all the same.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can't ask new questions, so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Presumably the system has disallowed you from asking questions because of: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans Members with question bans are encouraged to improve existing questions, but changing a question in a way that invalidates old answers---which both violates site norms and makes existing content less useful---is certainly not an improvement.

Comment: I'll wait a while (2-5 days). If no one else answers, I'll accept yours.

Comment: That sounds prudent. If one is really restricted to constants, power functions, exp, and log, and their combinations via $+, -, \cdot, /$, I'm not sure there is such a function. The lemma in my remark means that any such function must have infinitely many isolated local extrema, but it's not clear how to achieve that with the given atomic functions, all of which are constant or have finitely many local extrema.

Comment: Huh, interesting to note. Ok then, if I include trig functions, can you come up with one that is different than what you have now ($c \sin^2(a \pi)+ \sin^2(b \pi)$)?

Comment: In fact there is a $2$-parameter family $(x, y) \mapsto A \sin^2 \pi x + B \sin^2 \pi y$, where $A, B > 0$ and $|A| + |B| < 1$. Besides this, one can add finitely many "higher harmonics", that is, (positive) multiples of $\sin^2 \pi k x$ and $\sin^2 \pi k y$ for arbitrary integers $k$, provided that the sum of the coefficients is small enough to guarantee that $|f(x, y)| < 1$ for all $(x, y)$.

Comment: (And, of course, if you have one such function $f$, you can produce countable many others by adding an integer: $f + C$.)

Comment: By the way, if you permit use of either $\operatorname{mod}$ or $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$, by the way, then you can produce nontrigonometric examples by replacing $\sin$ with an appropriate triangle wave. These functions are available in many programming languages, but in the context of mathematics they are generally not considered elementary.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Though, how would it look like again? I forgot how to make triangle waves.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#Definitions

Answer (score 2):

An extremely trivial example: let $f$ be the constant function
$$f(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}$$
This works because the implication
$$ f(a,b)\in\Bbb Z \implies a,b\in\Bbb Z $$
is *vacuously* true.

Comment: Well, I guess it's technically true, but not exactly what I mean. +1 for cleverness, though.

Comment: @QuoteDave To be honest, it seems like there are not many functions like this! I want to see some other answers...

Comment: @QuoteDave I think you mean to specify the condition that $(a, b) \in \Bbb Z^2$ if and only if $f(a, b) \in \Bbb Z$, that is, that both the given implication *and* its converse hold.

Comment: @Travis I fixed that now.